# Using RegEx to extract Office 365 email UPN formatted

Tags: .net, regex, nintex-workflow

I am using the .NET regex syntax in a Nintex action and  would like to extract the email as shown below

i:0#.f|membership|daniel.Smith@domain.onmicrosoft.com

Now I think the approach is match the i:0#.f|membership bit but exclude it then match the rest. I would appreciate any help on this.  I did try this expression which did match some on the above.

```
(?<=)(i:0#.f|membership).
```

Daniel

Comment: Since it is for Nintex, you may try `[^|]+$` (for matching), or `^.*\|` for replacing.

Comment: You are impressive . Thanks but can you explain please.  Expresso is installed as per your previous advice but it is does't actually say much other than "Any character not in this class ....."

Comment: Yes, Expresso does not explain character classes, though sometimes that would be quite handy. However, in this case, it is basic, there is little to explain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you plan to use the Extract mode with Nintex, you may use

```
[^|]+$
```

to match 1 or more characters other than `|` that are at the end of the string. The `[^...]` is called a [**negated character class**](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html#negated) that contains literal symbols or ranges that are NOT to be matched, and everything else gets matched:

> The result is that the [negated] character class matches any character that is not in the character class.

See the [regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5B%5E%7C%5D%2B%24&i=i%3A0%23.f%7Cmembership%7Cdaniel.Smith%40domain.onmicrosoft.com)

Alternatively, you might use a replace action with

```
^.*\|
```

and replace with empty text. See [this demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5E.*%5C%7C&i=i%3A0%23.f%7Cmembership%7Cdaniel.Smith%40domain.onmicrosoft.com&r=).

The point here is that we first match the string start and then use backtracking with a greedy dot (`.*`) to get to the last literal `|`, and remove the whole match.

Comment: Thanks. I thin I understand the first demo. I think I may need to read up the second. Thanks very much .. Now I stand a chance of building my State machine!

Comment: Actually, the upvote didn't go through - the number of upvotes is still zero (see the number between twi up anddown arrows on top to the left of my answer).